# Retrieving non-message events in chat history in Telethon

Tags: telethon

I want to be able to retrieve events like this "xxx joined the group via invite link" or "xxx added yyy". I do get these messages with iter_messages, but they are empty. I guess I'm looking for something like .eventtype or something? I haven't found anything in the documentation

Comment: Are you looking for `message.action`?

Comment: That's it. Too obvious. Thank you

Comment: To see the members coming from Telegram, you have https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/message.html; to see the properties offered by Telethon, you have https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/objects-reference.html (keep inheritance in mind).